# how to download and convert a pre-trained "inception_v3" example in Tensorflow format:?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, snpe

I am just starting to use `tensor flow` while `downloading ML file`by using python API and I am getting the below error

> "C:\Users\IVISSW\Desktop\snpe-1.12.0> python
>   ./models/inception_v3/scripts/setup_inceptionv3.py -a
>   ./temp-assets-cache -d   File
>   "./models/inception_v3/scripts/setup_inceptionv3.py", line 159
>       except Exception, err:
>                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Is there any solution for that, I tried lots of stuff but could not find any suitable solution.

I am following [this tutorial](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-neural-processing-engine-ai/getting-started)

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: i am downloading the snapdragon sdk and using tensor flow as well all are instruction given in the qualcomm neural processing engine AI but this command is not working the instruction is given for Ubuntu only.

Comment: i am trouble with this only code is running fine but after the code i got exception file not found due to this only.

Comment: Apparently, there is a syntax error. Check the code near the line 159 in "setup_inceptionv3.py" and check for typing errors.

Comment: can you give me some work soluiotn on that

Comment: @LahiruKarunaratne any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

SNPE requires Python 2, make sure you are not running Python 3 by default.

Check with

```
python --version
```